# select maven modules at Jenkins/Hudson builds

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, parameterized

I have a lot modules for my Jenkins build server. Instead of declaring new modules for each of them, I would like to share a common configuration and select my modules before starting my build in a tree view. Let's say my root parent project has A,B,C,D projects and each of them has A1,A2,B1,B2,B3 etc... I would like to choose B1,A1 only to build.

Is there any plugin for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a feature of Maven3 [advanced reactor options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) and choose which project you would like to build, i.e.:

```
mvn -pl B1,A1
```

You can use additional switches to decide how to handle dependant projects:

```
-pl, --projects
    Build specified reactor projects instead of all projects
-am, --also-make
    If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list
-amd, --also-make-dependents
    If project list is specified, also build projects that depend on projects on the list
```

In this scenario providing a list of projects is a piece of cake, using project parameters as the most obvious example. You can even create a plugin to support custom parameter type with Maven modules names and artifacts IDs as names/values.